# How to secure a web-app with the mac address

Tags: javascript, ajax, licensing, networking

I'd like to know if it's possible to get the mac address of a client with javascript, It would be a good way to secure a web-app. (eg. Limit one license p/ Mac Adress)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. It's the same security issue.  You can't do this with Flash either.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea.

The MAC address can be changed programmatically.

Comment: (+1) And can be changed even in hardware administrator menu in windows XP, or with the ifconfig command in Unix sistems.

Answer (score 2):

1/ You can't. MACs only travel in the local network.

2/ Javascript is a weird choice for license enforcements.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good strategy. What if a network card burns out and the client will have to replace it? These things happen.